# Blogger: Is There A "If Not Search" Condition?

Tags: xml, blogger

Is there a condition for making something NOT show up during search? I have sidebar that I only want to show on items(posts). However, if I use the item condition, then the gadgets within the sidebar cannot be edited within the admin layout. I'm trying to accomplish this without CSS & Javascript.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... But what I do know is that there are new blogger templates that already allow you to have widgets/gadgets showing only in item pages but still be possible to access them thru the admin panel. I'm using one of those myself from the Emporio series...although heavy modified by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of search pages on Blogger `search.query` and `search.label`, you can use `not` operator with them like the following:

```
<!-- if page is not query or label -->
<b:if cond='not data:view.isSearch'>


<!-- if page is not query -->
<b:if cond='not data:view.search.query'>


<!-- if page is not label -->
<b:if cond='not data:view.search.label'>
```

Comment: You were close, it is `<b:if cond='not data:view.isSearch'>`. Change your answer to that and I will accept it.

Comment: Ok, `isSearch` targets the two types of search pages `search.label` and `search.query`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `not data:view.isSearch` the sidebar will be hidden in labels and index pages, you can use this instead:

```
<b:if cond='data:view.search.query == ""'>
   //...
</b:if>
```

Answer (score -1):

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item" or data:view.isLayoutMode'>

[sidebar here]

</b:if>